# Android emulator retrofit api call does not respond first few requests

Tags: android, android-emulator, retrofit

I am developing an app with the movie database API (TMDB) and jetpack compose. as from last week suddenly my first few GET request gets timeout and after few tries it works normal. the app works fine on physical device but no matter the emulator api level, it does not get a respond for first few calls.
heres the code for okhttp and retrofit

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .callTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
): Retrofit {
    val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
    val json = Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
        .build()
}
```

i changed the emulator wifi dns to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and nothing changes.
heres the code for some of the endpoints:

```
@GET("movie/popular")
suspend fun getPopularMovies(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
    @Query("page") page: Int = 1
): MovieApiResponse


@GET("movie/top_rated")
suspend fun getTopRatedMovies(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
    @Query("page") page: Int = 1
): MovieApiResponse


@GET("trending/movie/day")
suspend fun getTrendingMovies(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY,
    @Query("page") page: Int = 1
): MovieApiResponse
```

full log:

```
2022-07-30 17:51:12.061 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=102.27ms min=1.40ms max=1401.67ms count=15
2022-07-30 17:51:12.264 27601-27601 handleSearchError       com.kavrin.marvin                    D  call
2022-07-30 17:51:12.267 27601-28636 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  --> GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/438148?api_key=***********&append_to_response=videos%2Cimages%2Ccredits%2Creviews%2Crecommendations%2Csimilar
2022-07-30 17:51:12.267 27601-28636 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  --> END GET
2022-07-30 17:51:12.277   360-28638 resolv                  netd                                 D  GetAddrInfoHandler::run: {102 102 102 983142 10154 0}
2022-07-30 17:51:12.278   360-28638 resolv                  netd                                 D  resolv_getaddrinfo: explore_fqdn(): ai_family=0 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
2022-07-30 17:51:12.279   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  doQuery: (1, 28)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.279   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nmkquery: (QUERY, IN, AAAA)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.279   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  doQuery: (1, 1)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nmkquery: (QUERY, IN, A)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_cache_lookup: lookup
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_cache_lookup: lookup
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_cache_lookup: NOT IN CACHE (STALE ENTRY 0x77536e3352d0DISCARDED)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  _cache_remove_p: entry 204 removed (count=21)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_populate_res_for_net: netid=102
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: NS stats: S 53 + E 0 + T 11 + I 0 = 64, rtt = 157, min_samples = 8
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: success rate 82
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: NS stats: S 13 + E 0 + T 6 + I 0 = 19, rtt = 144, min_samples = 8
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: success rate 68
2022-07-30 17:51:12.280   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: Querying server (# 1) address = 8.8.8.8:53
2022-07-30 17:51:12.281   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: new DG socket
2022-07-30 17:51:12.282   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  get_timeout: using timeout of 5000 msec
2022-07-30 17:51:12.283   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 56 retrying_poll
2022-07-30 17:51:12.284   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_cache_lookup: NOT IN CACHE (STALE ENTRY 0x77534e32ae70DISCARDED)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.284   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  _cache_remove_p: entry 203 removed (count=20)
2022-07-30 17:51:12.284   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  resolv_populate_res_for_net: netid=102
2022-07-30 17:51:12.286   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: NS stats: S 53 + E 0 + T 11 + I 0 = 64, rtt = 157, min_samples = 8
2022-07-30 17:51:12.286   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: success rate 82
2022-07-30 17:51:12.287   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: NS stats: S 13 + E 0 + T 6 + I 0 = 19, rtt = 144, min_samples = 8
2022-07-30 17:51:12.287   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_usable_server: success rate 68
2022-07-30 17:51:12.287   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: Querying server (# 1) address = 8.8.8.8:53
2022-07-30 17:51:12.287   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: new DG socket
2022-07-30 17:51:12.287   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  get_timeout: using timeout of 5000 msec
2022-07-30 17:51:12.288   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 57 retrying_poll
2022-07-30 17:51:13.076 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=6.99ms min=1.25ms max=131.10ms count=38
2022-07-30 17:51:14.078 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=11.56ms min=1.30ms max=263.64ms count=31
2022-07-30 17:51:15.110 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=9.99ms min=1.15ms max=247.49ms count=33
2022-07-30 17:51:16.126 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=10.27ms min=1.28ms max=246.71ms count=32
2022-07-30 17:51:16.871   766-864   EGL_emulation           com.android.systemui                 D  app_time_stats: avg=16841.67ms min=16841.67ms max=16841.67ms count=1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.256 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.62ms min=1.32ms max=231.15ms count=33
2022-07-30 17:51:17.284   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 56 retrying_poll timeout
2022-07-30 17:51:17.284   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: 1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.284   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_nsend: used send_dg 0 terrno: 110
2022-07-30 17:51:17.284   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_set_sample: rcode = 255, sec = 0
2022-07-30 17:51:17.285   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_cache_add_stats_sample_locked: adding sample to stats, next = 3, count = 64
2022-07-30 17:51:17.285   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: Querying server (# 2) address = 8.8.4.4:53
2022-07-30 17:51:17.286   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: new DG socket
2022-07-30 17:51:17.286   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  get_timeout: using timeout of 5000 msec
2022-07-30 17:51:17.287   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 58 retrying_poll
2022-07-30 17:51:17.292   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 57 retrying_poll timeout
2022-07-30 17:51:17.292   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: 1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_nsend: used send_dg 0 terrno: 110
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_set_sample: rcode = 255, sec = 0
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_cache_add_stats_sample_locked: adding sample to stats, next = 4, count = 64
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: Querying server (# 2) address = 8.8.4.4:53
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  send_dg: new DG socket
2022-07-30 17:51:17.293   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  get_timeout: using timeout of 5000 msec
2022-07-30 17:51:17.294   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 59 retrying_poll
2022-07-30 17:51:17.540   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 58 retrying_poll returning 1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_nsend: used send_dg 303 terrno: 0
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_set_sample: rcode = 0, sec = 254
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_cache_add_stats_sample_locked: adding sample to stats, next = 19, count = 19
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: got answer:
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  answer_getTTL: TTL = 9
2022-07-30 17:51:17.541   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  _cache_add_p: entry 205 added (count=21)
2022-07-30 17:51:17.542   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 I  cache_dump_mru_locked: MRU LIST (21):  205 192 202 178 193 201 196 200 199 185 184 172 171 158 157 156 155 47 46 21 18
2022-07-30 17:51:17.542   360-28640 resolv                  netd                                 D  doQuery: rcode=0, ancount=9
2022-07-30 17:51:17.547   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  retrying_poll: 59 retrying_poll returning 1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.547   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_nsend: used send_dg 143 terrno: 0
2022-07-30 17:51:17.547   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_stats_set_sample: rcode = 0, sec = 253
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  res_cache_add_stats_sample_locked: adding sample to stats, next = 20, count = 20
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  res_nsend: got answer:
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  answer_getTTL: TTL = 1
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  _cache_add_p: entry 206 added (count=22)
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 I  cache_dump_mru_locked: MRU LIST (22):  206 205 192 202 178 193 201 196 200 199 185 184 172 171 158 157 156 155 47 46 21 18
2022-07-30 17:51:17.548   360-28641 resolv                  netd                                 D  doQuery: rcode=0, ancount=5
2022-07-30 17:51:18.456 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.18ms min=1.32ms max=230.86ms count=40
2022-07-30 17:51:19.655 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.62ms min=1.21ms max=230.51ms count=37
2022-07-30 17:51:20.856 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.32ms min=1.36ms max=230.19ms count=39
2022-07-30 17:51:22.057 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=9.25ms min=0.97ms max=231.68ms count=36
2022-07-30 17:51:22.656   360-404   netd                    netd                                 I  setProcSysNet(4, 2, wlan0, retrans_time_ms, 750) <0.16ms>
2022-07-30 17:51:22.656   360-404   netd                    netd                                 I  setProcSysNet(4, 2, wlan0, ucast_solicit, 10) <0.03ms>
2022-07-30 17:51:22.656   360-404   netd                    netd                                 I  setProcSysNet(6, 2, wlan0, retrans_time_ms, 750) <0.07ms>
2022-07-30 17:51:22.657   360-404   netd                    netd                                 I  setProcSysNet(6, 2, wlan0, ucast_solicit, 10) <0.07ms>
2022-07-30 17:51:23.257 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=9.12ms min=1.35ms max=231.47ms count=37
2022-07-30 17:51:24.457 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.50ms min=1.32ms max=248.12ms count=40
2022-07-30 17:51:25.655 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.10ms min=1.37ms max=229.71ms count=40
2022-07-30 17:51:26.856 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=11.20ms min=1.41ms max=263.79ms count=37
2022-07-30 17:51:28.056 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.72ms min=1.30ms max=247.14ms count=39
2022-07-30 17:51:29.257 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.67ms min=1.30ms max=247.89ms count=39
2022-07-30 17:51:30.457 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=9.08ms min=1.34ms max=247.93ms count=39
2022-07-30 17:51:31.655 27601-27629 EGL_emulation           com.kavrin.marvin                    D  app_time_stats: avg=8.85ms min=1.34ms max=230.11ms count=40
2022-07-30 17:51:32.268 27601-28636 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
2022-07-30 17:51:32.278 27601-27601 handleSearchError       com.kavrin.marvin                    D  call
2022-07-30 17:51:36.871   766-864   EGL_emulation           com.android.systemui                 D  app_time_stats: avg=19999.61ms min=19999.61ms max=19999.61ms count=1
```

okHttpLog:

```
2022-07-30 17:54:24.413 27601-28835 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  --> GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/438148?api_key=**********&append_to_response=videos%2Cimages%2Ccredits%2Creviews%2Crecommendations%2Csimilar
2022-07-30 17:54:24.413 27601-28835 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  --> END GET
2022-07-30 17:54:44.416 27601-28835 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.kavrin.marvin                    I  <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

PS: emulator has internet connection and other apps works perfectly fine

Comment: Can you share some of your okHttp logs with us?

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: Have you tried to send the same request from Postman? I would say that the problem here is not with Retrofit.

Comment: I have tried and it is successful every time. the problem is just with the emulator. it's works fine with real device too

Answer (score 1):

Evertthing sounds ok, I suggest you test on a real device

Comment: it works normally in real device. my problem is with the emulator